# Application continuity with Universal Connection Pool java JDBC Oracle 12c

Tags: java, oracle, transactions, oracle12c, ojdbc

I am trying to achieve application continuity with Oracle 12c database & Oracle UCP(Universal Connection Pool). As per the official documentation, I have implemented the following in my application. I am using ojdbc8.jar along with the equivalent ons.jar and the ucp.jar in my application.

```
PoolDataSource  pds = oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
```

Properties as per oracle documentation:

```
pds.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleDataSourceImpl");
pds.setUser("username");
pds.setPassword("password");
pds.setInitialPoolSize(10);
pds.setMinPoolSize(10);
pds.setMaxPoolSize(20);
pds.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);
pds.setONSConfiguration("nodes=IP_1:ONS_PORT_NUMBER,IP_2:ONS_PORT_NUMBER");
pds.setValidateConnectionOnBorrow(true);
pds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@my_scan_name.my_domain_name.com:PORT_NUMBER/my_service_name");
// I have also tried using the TNS-Like URL as well. //
```

However, I am not able to acheive application continuity. I have some inflight transactions that I expect to replay when I bring down the RAC node on which my database service is running. What I observe is that my service migrates to the next available RAC node in the cluster, however, my in-flight transactions fail. What expect to happen over here is that the drivers will automatically restart the failed in-flight transactions. However, I dont see this happening. The queries that I fire are the database, sometimes I see them being triggered again on the database side, but we see Connection Closed Exception on the client side

According to some documentation, application continuity allows the application to mask outages from the user. My doubt here is whether my understanding that the application continuity will replay the SQL Statement that were in-flight when the outage occured is correct or is the the true meaning of application continuity something else.

I have refered to some blogs such as this,
https://martincarstenbach.wordpress.com/2013/12/13/playing-with-application-continuity-in-rac-12c/

The example mentioned here does not seem to be intended for replaying of in-flight SQL statements.

Is application continuity capable or replaying the in-flight SQL statements during a outage, or is FCF and application continuity only restore the state of the connection object and make it usable by the user post the outage has occured. If the earlier is true, then please guide me if I am missing anything in the application level settings in my code that is keeping me from achieving replay.

Comment: it depends on conditions. I did test it is it seems that JDBC driver has some internal limit for volume of changes remembered. If you exceed this this threshold, you will get java.sql.sqlRecoverableException, when connection is killed. I could not find and documented value for this threshold.

Answer (score 3):

Yes your understanding is correct. With the replay driver, Application Continuity can replay in-flight work so that an outage is invisible to the application and the application can continue, hence the name of the feature. The only thing that's visible from the application is a slight delay on the JDBC call that hit the outage. What's also visible is an increase in memory usage on the JDBC side because the driver maintains a queue of calls. What happens under the covers is that, upon outage, your physical JDBC connection will be replaced by a brand new one and the replay driver will replay its queue of calls.

Now there could be cases where replay fails. For example replay will fail if the data has changed. Replay will also be disabled if you have multiple transactions within a "request". A "request" starts when a connection is borrowed from the pool and ends when it's returned back to the pool. Typically a "request" matches a servlet execution. If within this request you have more than one "commit" then replay will be disabled at runtime and the replay driver will stop queuing. Also note that auto-commit must be disabled.

[I'm part of the Oracle team that designed and implemented this feature]

Comment: By an in-flight query, do you also mean that the cursor on the JDBC ResultSet is restored to its position before the failure. (For example if a query is about to return 1 million results and we have moved up to lets say the 10000th row, the cursor will be restored to this position?)

Comment: Thank you for making it clear @Jean . I have also tried setting the auto commit off. However, I was not able to achieve the desired results. Also, the majority of the documentations and the blogs I have referred do not provide any concrete example of replay while using UCP. Can you point me to such documentation/blog/example that illustrates the replay of in-flight transactions using UCP ?

Comment: @AkshayGehi Yes all the JDBC calls are replayed including resultSet.next() so the position will be reset to what it was before the outage.

Comment: @RishiD Martin's blog has a nice code sample: https://martincarstenbach.wordpress.com/2013/12/13/playing-with-application-continuity-in-rac-12c/

Comment: Replay worked by disconnecting my machine from the LAN while the database was being queried.A pause of a few seconds and then the query was re-fired and resumed returning the data. When shutdown immediate was used on the node where the query was being fired, the following error was received and the query did not replay: Cannot get Connection from Datasource: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12521, TNS:listener does not currently know of instance requested in connect descriptor. The database is connected using a SCAN name

Comment: Application Continuity handles unplanned outages. A "shutdown immediate" isn't unplanned. "shutdown immediate" will let your transaction complete. The error "TNS:listener does not currently know of instance requested in connect descriptor" indicates that you're connecting to a specific instance that's down.

Answer (score 1):

I think the jdbc connection string could be your problem:

```
pds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@my_scan_name.my_domain_name.com:PORT_NUMBER/my_service_name");
```

You are using a so called `EZConnect` String but this is not supported with AC.

```
Alias (or URL) = (DESCRIPTION=
(CONNECT_TIMEOUT= 120)(RETRY_COUNT=20) RETRY_DELAY=3)(TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)
(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=primary-scan)(PORT=1521)))
(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=secondary-scan)(PORT=1521)))
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=gold-cloud)))
```